# Sails.js Count members of model / assiciation

Tags: javascript, node.js, count, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to count members of a team in a table like this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot sails.js count function]

This is my "logic" but it wont work :(

```
  fn: async function () {

    var teams = await Team.find();
    var users = await User.find();

    var countMembers = await Team.count().where(users.team === teams.id);

    // Respond with view.
    return {teams, countMembers};

  }
```

The Table/ Model User is so, that 1 user can have 1 team.
I Just want to count the members in the teams overview page.

Comment: teams is an array of teams, you cant do `teams.id`, this also works with `users.team`

Comment: Also any of my ideas wont work:

`var teams = await Team.find();
  var users = await User.find().where({ 'team': { '===': teams.id}});`

Comment: @NikitaMazur How do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you set up your modules i.e. with the attribute `users: {collection: 'User', via: 'team'}` for the collection of `Teams`, and `User` module with the attribute `team: {model: 'Team'}`.

One-to-many docs: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many#one-to-many

```js
fn: async function () {

    // Populate and count for many-to-one relationship (one team has many members)
    var teams = await Team.find().populate('users');
    teams = teams.map(team => ({
      ...team,
      countMembers: team.users.length,
    }));

    // Respond with a view.
    return { teams };

}
```

In your EJS view use:

```js
<% teams.forEach(team => { %>
 <%= team.countMembers %>
<% }) %>
```

Check here the options to take account of the limit of populated items to avoid mistakes in the counted value: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/populate

Alternatively, you could use native querys:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/datastores/send-native-query#-sendnativequery-

Or even low level adapter usage:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/tutorials/using-mongo-db

Comment: Thanks! 

Do you know, how to access a list of the users? 
Tried this: 
`countMembers: team.users.emailAddress`

Comment: Populated fields are arrays, so you need to use a for or forEach or `team.users[0].emailAddress`.